# Is it possible to have a functional prefix text in discord? like hover or clickable

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am new to Discord and I found how to create a bot from : https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-create-a-discord-bot-under-15-minutes-fb2fd0083844 but I think this is not I wanted.

My goal, if it is possible. During a chat, some of people may chat a word like !heroOne or !heroTwo , if they hover it. it may display a html tooltip from my web app or if it is clicked it will redirect to a specific page of my web app?

I don't think so if I need to create a bot but I think it is a plugin or something. Any idea about my case?

Comment: Your particular use case is not possible. There is nothing in Discord's feature set that allows you to provide your own tooltips or redirects for html links. Additionally, you cannot modify message sent by other users, so there would be no way to make `!heroOne` into a link that can then be clicked and redirected to your web app. Your best option would be using a bot. The bot can look for incoming messages from users that contain `!heroOne` (for example) and post a new message containing the link the the particular page in your web app.

Comment: @Anu6is Markdown exactly like [this](https://discordapp.com/) is actually supported in Discord, although only within rich embeds or webhooks.

Comment: Yeah, I know markdown is supported. I really meant in regards to adding hover/mouseover functionally to a **user's** message (this isn't possible). When I spoke of having the bot send a follow-up message and providing a link, yes, that link can be placed in an embed or sent via a webhook utilizing markdown as desired...should have expounded a little more :)

Comment: Yeah, that specific piece of it would indeed be impossible, but the message could be deleted and resent by the bot, or a real response added.

Comment: make sense, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Markdown within a rich embed to produce something like [this](https://discordapp.com/) (redirects to Discord's website). However, the bot would have to send its own message with it in response.

```js
var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.addField('**Title**', '[click on me](https://discordapp.com/)');

message.channel.send(embed)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Keep in mind that this specific styling only works in certain places in a rich embed.

Comment: thanks slothiful, I think I can make it using this method